# RegEx search one word or one char from list

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble formulating a regex string to match " - " or any character from this array [ _-.].
This my example string doesn't work ( - |[ _\-\.])

My test program in Java:

```
cutAddressStreet("strassen name 1344"); // "strassen name" ok
cutAddressStreet("strassen name-1344"); // "strassen name" ok
cutAddressStreet("strassen name - 1344"); // "strassen name -"  <- Problem
cutAddressStreet("strassen name,1344"); // ""  ok
```

```
public static String cutAddressStreet(String sFull)
{
   String sRet = "";
   String sRegEx = "^(.*)( - |[ _\\-\\.])(\\d{1,5})(.*)$";
   if (sFull.matches(sRegEx))
   { // Yes , this is Street with Number
      String sStreet = sFull.replaceFirst(sRegEx, "$1");
      System.out.println("cut=\"" + sStreet + "\" from " + sFull);
      sRet = sStreet;
   }
   return sRet;
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZUg5Z3/1

Comment: unfortunately no effect

Comment: try `"^(.*?)([ _\\-.]-|[ _\\-.])(\\d{1,5})(.*)$"`

Comment: Sorry, bad pattern error, see
https://regex101.com/r/PgXNBR/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only replacing with capture group 1, you don't need 3 capture groups in the pattern. The first `.*` matches the whole string so that one should be non greedy.

The `-` in the character class can be at the end so you don' have to escape it, and you don't have to escape the dot in the character class.

In the code you can directly `return sStreet;` instead of overwriting the string `sRet` first.

```
public static String cutAddressStreet(String sFull)
{
    String sRet = "";
    String sRegEx = "^(.*?)(?: - |[ _.-])\\d{1,5}$";
    if (sFull.matches(sRegEx))
    {
        String sStreet = sFull.replaceFirst(sRegEx, "$1");
        System.out.println("cut=\"" + sStreet + "\" from " + sFull);
        return sStreet;
    }
    return sRet;
}
```

The output of the code:

```
cut="strassen name" from strassen name 1344
cut="strassen name" from strassen name-1344
cut="strassen name" from strassen name - 1344
```

Comment: Thanks very much,
one never stops learning !